# Passing a string gives a different ourcome to passing a string variable

Tags: c#, itext

I tried finding an answer for this but .

I have this function that is supposed to create a formatted paragraph.
When I pass it an html string like `"<b>Test</b>"` I get the bold text in the pdf as expected.

However when I pass a string variable with the same value I don't get a formatted text but instead I just get the original string in the pdf.

```
private Paragraph CreateSimpleHtmlParagraph(string text)
    {
        //Our return object
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();

        //ParseToList requires a StreamReader instead of just text
        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(text))
        {
            //Parse and get a collection of elements
            List<IElement> elements = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr, null);
            foreach (IElement e in elements)
            {
                //Add those elements to the paragraph
                p.Add(e);
            }
        }
        //Return the paragraph
        return p;
    }
```

Comment: Look for a difference between the strings that you pass as `text`, it must be there.

Comment: The two strings aren't getting inserted in the exact same place in the document.  Without see all the tags I can't give a better answer.

Comment: Try this: "&lt;b&gt;Test&lt;/b&gt;". Did you get it?

Comment: Please do not use `HTMLWorker`. Use `XMLWorker` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much guys. I checked the variable at runtime and it was in HTML format (eg: `&lt` instead of `<`). I had to use the [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) function on the variable and that worked out perfectly.